# How do I enable logging in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a Ruby/Rails newbie, but not a development newbie.

I have the following code defined in iniatializer.rb:

```
def logger
  if defined?(RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER)
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

I want to enable logging of messages in my Ruby/Rails application.

And in some Ruby/Rails code, I have

```
  logger.info "Email attachment: #{size} #{filename}"
```

\ruby\bin>ruby --version gives:
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i386-mingw32]

How would I change the logger definition so that logger.info goes into a file that I can open up and read? Please include necessary require/include as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your rails < 3.X then use below code

```
def logger
  if defined?(RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER)
    Logger.new('log/my_log.log')
  else 
    nil 
  end
end
```

If your rails > 3.X then replace RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER with Rails.logger in above code

```
def logger
  if defined?(Rails.logger)
    Logger.new('log/my_log.log')
  else 
    nil 
  end
end
```

Comment: Question is very specific. How would I change the logger definition, not write new code...

Thanks.

Comment: In your logger defination just reloace RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER with "Logger.new('log/my_log.log')" inside your if block. dont change the condition.so your code is   `if defined?(RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER)
    Logger.new('log/my_log.log')
  else
    nil
  end`

Comment: Subbarao, Frederick said RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER has been removed, so will your code help???

Comment: if you are using < rails 3.X then use `if defined?(RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER) Logger.new('log/my_log.log') else nil end`. If > 3.X then `if defined?(Rails.logger) Logger.new('log/my_log.log') else nil end` will work

Comment: Subbarao, can you amend your answer above so I can mark it and set it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

`RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER` was removed a long time ago. The new name is `Rails.logger`. This will be created for you when rails loads.

Comment: And there's nothing I can do with your answer. 

How do I check Rails.logger is logging to a log file then? If it is not enabled, how do I enable it? How do I set it?

Telling me it's removed or deprecated gives me nothing to work on. I need to enable logging. Please provide useful information.

Comment: My point was that you don't need to do anything - just use Rails.logger (defaults to log/development.log)

Comment: Frederick, so in the code above, since RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER has been removed, does that or doesn't that mean logger is defined as nil? So, doesn't that mean I still need to do something?

Comment: That logger method you've defined will return nil yes. You could change it to return Rails.logger instead or you could just use Rails.logger directly

Comment: Frederick, thanks, that's what I did (I'm a newbie to Rails/Ruby, not newbie to programming).